# How do I set the gravity of a plane world

Tags: libgdx, box2d

As you can see in the image, the character is set to move on a ground plane, however that causes an issue with Box2d's gravitational pull.
The player can go sideways, upwards and downwards on the plane. 
Is there any way I can use gravity in this case?

[image: The game player on the plane]

Comment: I got confused at the first comment, sorry. The character can for forward and backward (only visually, adjusting the y axis), and he cannot jump, so he can go near the edge of the cliff or near the screen. by gravitation I mean a force that can drag him, like behind the surface.

Comment: Sorry about that. What I'm getting at is, are your physics purely side-on like a 2D platformer (side to side along a ground line, plus jumping/falling)? Or do you have the ability to walk up and down the ground plane, like in a Beat-Em-Up (eg. Turtles in Time, Streets of Rage, Castle Crashers)? Your screenshot looks like it might be the latter, so I wanted to confirm.

Comment: Exactly like the latter, in a Beat-Em-Up style.

Comment: Can you give an example of a situation where you'd experience "a force that can drag him, like behind the surface"?

Comment: I didn't know how to explain this, but the only thing I'm after is the reduction of speed when the player moves, right now there is no gravity, which causes the character to just float, slowly decreasing its speed. The situation I was describing was not a good example, the character can't "fall" behind the surface.

Comment: Ah, are you really asking about "friction" (a reduction in speed when sliding along a surface) or "damping" (a reduction in speed over time) and not "gravity" (an acceleration downward)?

Comment: Hmm I think it's about damping, the surface is not mapped as a body (or it should be?). Should I map the surface and set a friction variable in the fixture?

Comment: No you shouldn't do that. Instead, edit your question so it's describing your actual problem (ie. floaty/drifting character movement) and how you want the character to behave instead. Sharing the code you're using for moving your player currently would also help.

Comment: Alright, thank you for your guidance, I would fix the question as soon as I can.

Answer (score 1):

Reading the comments I think Box2D is overkill to achieve what you want. Why not just have a velocity vector and decrease it over time?

```
    Vector3 velocity = new Vector3();

    //Update method
    if (Gdx.input.isKeyJustPressed(Input.Keys.RIGHT)) {
        velocity.x = horizontalSpeed * delta;
    } else if (Gdx.input.isKeyJustPressed(Input.Keys.LEFT)){
        velocity.x = -horizontalSpeed * delta;
    } else {
        // Reduce velocity if no key is pressed
        velocity.x *= .9f;
    }
    // Do same for Y axis, with a different speed variable since it's not fully top down.

    // Then add velocity to your position
    position.add(velocity);
```

You can also use the deceleration method for acceleration by increasing the velocity until your max speed is reached. This however does have a bigger impact on controlling your character then deceleration and is more often used in racing games to simulate a car.